# How to make "Textured Window" look like preference pane

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

What controls can I use to make the "Textured Window" look like the tabbed view type look of most OS X applications? Like this:
[image]

So far all I have is this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want a textured window. Use a regular window with an `NSToolbar`.